# C program that results in a static and non-static declaration error

Tags: c, declaration

Here is the code from my program that has a issue:

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    int main(void)
    {
    int funcnum;

    printf("Welcome \n");
    printf("Please enter a number\n");
    scanf("%i",&funcnum);

    switch(funcnum)  //funcnum is the variable you are checking for a match
    {          //Open curly!
        case 1:  // is funcnum==1?
            printf("You entered 1. This is now the Turkey Time function.\n"); // if funcnum==1, this will happen.
            {
              //DECLARE the "cookTime" function.(Above, outside the MAIN function)
              //It will return a float, and is expecting two floats.
              float cookTime (float);

              //Below is a "global" variable -meaning available to all functions. These are declared outside of any function.
              float cTim;

              float weight;

              printf("Welcome to the turkey timer...\n");

              printf("Please enter a turkey weight \n");
              scanf("%f",&weight);

              cookTime (weight); //Calling (jumping to) the cookTime function and sending it "weight" variable.  

              printf("Cooking time is %.1f minutes.\n\n",cTim); //printing the returned value cTim.
              printf("\tThank you for choosing the MaiCorp Timing System, don't forget the gravy! \n");

              //DEFINE the  function. Note -no semicolon. (just like in main's definition above!)
              float cookTime (float w)
              {   
                cTim = w*15;
                return cTim; //We are sending cTim back to where we left Main.
              }
            }
            break; //break makes the statement end and jump out of the curlies.
        case 2:  // is funcnum==2?
            printf("You entered 2. This is now the Area function.\n");
            {
              //DECLARE the "area" function.(Above, outside the MAIN function)
              //Looking at the declaration we can see that this function will return an int, and is expecting two int's.
              int area (int, int);

              //Here we declare a global variable.  Meaning a variable that is available to all functions. These are declared outside of any function.
              int ans;

              int len,wid;

              printf("Welcome to the rectangle area calculator...\n");
              printf("Please enter a length\n");
              scanf("%i",&len);
              printf("Please enter a width\n");
              scanf("%i",&wid);


              area (len,wid);    //Calling the "area" function, sending it the len and wid integers..

              printf("Area is %i.\n",ans); //printing the returned value "ans"

              //DEFINE the area function. Note -no semicolon. (just like in main's definition above!)

              int area (int L, int W)
              {
                ans = L*W;
                return ans; 
              }
            }
            break;
        default:    //default catches all non matches.
            printf("You did not enter 1 or 2, meaning that you are not running a function this time.\n");
            break;
    }  //close curly!
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, the gcc version 4.6.3 compiler gives this:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:35:21: error: static declaration of 'cookTime' follows non-
static declaration
           float cookTime (float w)
                 ^~~~~~~~
main.c:17:21: note: previous declaration of 'cookTime' was here
           float cookTime (float);
                 ^~~~~~~~
main.c:67:19: error: static declaration of 'area' follows non-static 
declaration
           int area (int L, int W)
               ^~~~
main.c:47:19: note: previous declaration of 'area' was here
           int area (int, int);
               ^~~~

exit status 1
```

This program is written in C in case anyone needs to know the programming language that the program is written in.
I have tried to fix the program by putting in "{}"'s and other code but it came to be of no use (meaning that the error did not resolve).
It would be great if a reputable programmer can assist me with this issue.

Comment: Why do you have  `(Above, outside the MAIN function)` inside the main function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are declaring a function within the main...? That is not only bad practice, but judging by the code there it looks like it's illegal. Unless you put `static` in front of it.

If you want to use the function, do NOT put it's return type before using the function. Instead of:

```
int area( int L, int W);
```

use

```
area(int L, int W);
```

Really weird to define a function within the main. Like I said, I don't think it's allowed, but if you REALLY want to do it, I would suggest putting `static` in front of the function.

Better yet, make a `Name_goes_here.h` file and put the functions in there. Then,

`#include "Name_goes_here.h"`

and use the functions like I told you. (except instead of int L, int W, replace it with pre-declared variables L and W without int in front of it.)

Comment: You have a good answer, but your advise on "*leave it `int main()` rather than the void stuff*" is simply wrong. [**See What should main() return in C and C++?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) Here is the standard reference, See: [**C11 Standard (draft n1570) §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I changed it

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles.
2. properly prototypes the sub functions.
3. properly declares the sub functions.
4. eliminates most commentary that is just a repeat of the code.
5. Uses appropriate vertical spacing (between code blocks, between functions, between code activities).
6. fails to check the returned value from system functions (I.E. `scanf()`).
7. Follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
8. respects the right boundary of a printed output of the listing.
9. properly writes a 'float' literal

and now the proposed code:

```
#include "stdio.h"


// prototypes
int   area (int, int);
float cookTime (float);


int main(void)
{
    int funcnum;

    printf("Welcome \n");
    printf("Please enter a number\n");
    scanf("%i",&funcnum);

    switch(funcnum)  
    {
        case 1:  
            printf("You entered 1."
                   " This is now the Turkey Time function.\n"); 

            float weight;

            printf("Welcome to the turkey timer...\n");

            printf("Please enter a turkey weight \n");
            scanf("%f",&weight);

            float cTim = cookTime (weight);

            printf("Cooking time is %.1f minutes.\n\n",cTim);
            printf("\tThank you for choosing the MaiCorp Timing System, don't forget the gravy! \n");
            break;

        case 2:  
            printf("You entered 2."
                   " This is now the Area function.\n");

            int len;
            int wid;

            printf("Welcome to the rectangle area calculator...\n");

            printf("Please enter a length\n");
            scanf("%i",&len);

            printf("Please enter a width\n");
            scanf("%i",&wid);

            int ans = area (len,wid);

            printf("Area is %i.\n",ans);
            break;

        default:    
            printf("You did not enter 1 or 2,"
                   " meaning that you are not running"
                   " a function this time.\n");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
} // end function: main


int area (int L, int W)
{
    int ans = L*W;
    return ans;
} // end function: area


float cookTime (float w)
{
    float cTim = w*15.0f;   // << note the proper 'float' literal
    return cTim;
} // end function: cookTime
```